# How to connect two laptops wirelessly in Windows 7 for file sharing

Tags: file-sharing, wireless-networking

I want to know how to connect two laptops wirelessly in Windows 7, and how to share files between them.

Comment: Have you considered creating an ad-hoc wireless network on the one, and connecting the other to it? I expect you could use HomeGroup to achieve this, even, but I'm guessing.

Comment: you need to add a little bit more information in order to really answer this questions.  Please let us know if you are using this at home, or if this is a public place.  Do you have access to the router?

Comment: Create a Home Group to share files...http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/help/home-sweet-homegroup-networking-the-easy-way

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the first laptop wireless in ad-hoc mode and follow these steps:

1. open the Network and Sharing Center
2. Set Up a Connection or Network
3. Setup wireless ad hoc network
4. Select WPA2-Personal security
5. When finished, you will receive a notification that the network has been created
6. Your laptop will now broadcast this newly created wireless network and it will wait for other computer to connect.
7. Make sure you have set correct firewall mode to share folders.

This activity should not take more than 10 min.
Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a wireless router to connect both laptops, you do as Randolph suggested and set up an Ad Hock network to share files. See the link below.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Set-up-a-computer-to-computer-ad-hoc-network

.

For more info on sharing files using W7 see this
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/File-sharing-essentials

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention if you had a router available. If not, you need to create an [Ad-hoc network](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Set-up-a-computer-to-computer-ad-hoc-network).

Comment: You can also find more information about file sharing here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/File-sharing-essentials

Comment: This is what I automatically assumed, two laptops with no router.